# How to separate two projects from one solution and communicate with each other?

Tags: visual-studio, microservices

I have a two project linked with each other, Project A and Project B in same Visual Studio solutions.
Now the requirement is, I have to do separate projects, it means separate database, web site name, servers etc.

Now I want to know how I will communicate both the project each other using web API?

Answer (score 0):

Before starting separate I would suggest reading about DDD (Domain Driven Design) to make the rights choices about what functionality and classes could be in one microservice or the other.

Anyway, once you have separated the two services properly, so the communication between them would be minimum, there are mainly two ways to communicate with each other.

One is using synchronous communication using HTTP calls using some HTTP client for your language, for example, in java-spring applications is very common to use Webclient. The pros of this approach is that you don't have to deal with eventual consistency because all happens in the same thread, the main con is that you are coupling the services and if one of them fails the other will fail too.

The second approach is to use asynchronous messaging using some message broker like kafka. With this approach when something happen in one of the service, it will publish the event in the message broker and it will be consumed by the other. Ther is no direct communication so there can't be cascade failures but the problem is that you don't know when exactly the message will be consumed (eventual consistency)

As you see both options have pros and cons and it depends on your use case to choose one or the other